# Get Row Selected before MouseDown Event Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I got this XAML of my `Image-Row` in a Datagrid:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn  x:Name="imgSettings" Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image x:Name="imgSettings"  Source="img/settings_blue.png" Stretch="None" MouseDown="Row_DoubleClick" />
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="imgSettings" Property="Source" Value="/img/settings_white.png" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

My `Double Click` Event for the rows is:

```
private void Row_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Equipment classObj = clientDataGrid.SelectedItem as Equipment;
    string cellValue = classObj.EQNr;

    lblArtikel.Content = "Equipment: " + cellValue ;
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => tbControlETK.SelectedIndex = 1));
}
```

Which actually works, but now I tried now to get the same function for this image button, but this gives me a null exception because the MouseDown Event triggers before the Row gets selected... any solutions?

I already thought of a function for the image row where I can get the row of the sender or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search through the visual tree for DataGridRow gonna be selected and use them, if you find such one.

```
<Image x:Name="imgSettings"  Source="img/settings_blue.png" Stretch="None" MouseDown="Mouse_Down" />



private void Mouse_Down(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridRow gridRowGettingSelection = null;
            var visParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(sender as FrameworkElement);
            while (gridRowGettingSelection == null && visParent != null)
            {
                gridRowGettingSelection = visParent as DataGridRow;
                visParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(visParent);
            }
            if (gridRowGettingSelection == null) { return; }

            Equipment classObj = gridRowGettingSelection.DataContext as Equipment;
            string cellValue = classObj.EQNr;

            lblArtikel.Content = "Equipment: " + cellValue;
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => tbControlETK.SelectedIndex = 1));

        }
```

Comment: Amazing! Exactlty what i wanted

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm for getting "row index" when clicking on a "DataGridTemplateColumn" in WPF.